# Dijkstra's algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, c, dijkstra

I'm required to implement the Dijkstra's algorithm via ADT graph using the adjacency matrix representation for finding a shortest path by enhancing the pseudo code below using either C/C++ language.

```
procedure Dijkstra(G, w, r, Parent[0:n-1], Dist)
  for v← 0 to n-1 do
    Dist[v] ← ∞
    InTheTree[v] ← .false.
  endfor
  Parent[r] ←-1
  Dist[r] ←0
  for Stage ←1 to n-1 do 
    Select vertex u that minimises Dist[u] over all u such that InTheTree[u] = .false. 
    InTheTree[u] = .true.                                       // add u to T
    for each vertex v such that uv ∈ E do             // update Dist[v] and 
      if .not. InTheTree[v]  then                // Parent[v] arrays
        if Dist[u] + w(uv) < Dist[v]
          Dist[v] = Dist[u] + w(uv)
          Nearest[v] ←w(uv) 
          Parent[v] ← u
        endif
      endif
    endfor
  endfor
end Dijkstra
```

Here is my solution of code which is being coded in C++. My lecturer claim that the code does not meet the pseudocode requirements and I'm not sure 
where it went wrong so can anyone help me to spot what doesn't match between the code and the pseudocode?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define N 9

int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
   int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

   for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
     if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[n] <= min)
         min = dist[n], min_index = n;

   return min_index;
}
int printSolution(int dist[], int v)
{
   printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}
void dijkstra(int graph[N][N], int src)
{
     int dist[N];     

     bool sptSet[N];                         

     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        sptSet[i] = false;
     }

     dist[src] = 0;


     for (int count = 0; count < N-1; count++)
     {

       int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
            sptSet[u] = true;
       for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
         if (!sptSet[n] && graph[u][n] && dist[u] != INT_MAX 
                                       && dist[u]+graph[u][n] < dist[n])
            dist[n] = dist[u] + graph[u][n];
     }
     printSolution(dist, N);
}

int main()
{
   int graph[N][N] = {{0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                      {4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0},
                      {0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2},
                      {0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 4, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6},
                      {8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7},
                      {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0}
                     };

    dijkstra(graph, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nearest[v] ←() = Nearest[v] ←w(uv)

Comment: Not the issue, but usually you would write `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;` as `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {dist[i] = INT_MAX; sptSet[i] = false;}`; the comma operator is not usually used just to put several statements in a line.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thanks, I have edited accordingly. The problem was, this code does not match the pseudocode it seems. I would like to know which part it does not match.

Comment: Currently, the code doesn't compile. `sptSet[i] = false;` is outside the for loop (Which is why i tell everyone to ALWAYS put {} even if there's a single-line statement in it.

Comment: @LordZsolt already edited the correction.

Comment: I don't see you doing anything with `Nearest[v] ←w(uv)` and `Parent[r] ← u` (Pardon me, it's been a while since I wrote a Dijkstra myself, so I might not see where you use it). Also, how long did your professor spend looking at your code? If less then 5-10 seconds, he's ignorant and a jerk. Did you ask him why? Did he answer with anything?

Comment: The pseudocode method signature has source and destination, but yours only has one vertice.

Comment: Question 1: Do you need to implement `nearest` and `parent`?  Question 2: Is there a requirement to use a priority queue (min heap)?

Comment: @JS1 question 1: yes, furthermore I need to modified the code to solve some real time problem. But the the basic i need to solve the pseudocode first ;(
question2 : no requirement to use priority queue

Comment: The code currently doesn't compile: `sptSet[v] == false` needs to be `sptSet[n] == false`

Comment: I believe the goal is to find the shortest paths, not only the lengths of those paths. (And the pseudocode doesn't do any printing.) You would make things much easier for yourself if you used the same naming as the pseudocode. Does renaming "InTheTree" to "sptSet" really make anything clearer?

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious mismatch is that your code does not have anything corresponding to to the pseudocode's `Parent` array.  I take that as an output parameter, though it's not explicitly so marked.  As you seem to have recognized, it is not needed for computing only the *lengths* of the minimum paths, but it contains all the information about the actual steps in those paths, and that is often desired information.

You also have no analog of the pseudocode's `Nearest`; it would be a bit mean to complain about that, though, as `Nearest` is not a parameter to the routine, and the pseudocode does not show its elements ever being read.  As such, it does not appear to serve any useful purpose.

It appears that this code also does not quite match:

```
         if (!sptSet[n] && graph[u][n] && dist[u] != INT_MAX 
                                       && dist[u]+graph[u][n] < dist[n])
            dist[n] = dist[u] + graph[u][n];
```

The condition `&& dist[u] != INT_MAX` does not correspond to anything in the pseudocode. (It's also unnecessary, inasmuch as `u` was returned by `minDistance()`, and therefore that condition should always be satisfied).

Conceivably, your instructor may also be dissatisfied that you print the min path lengths instead of returning them.  It depends a bit on the pseudocode dialect, but I'd be inclined to take the appearance of `Dist` in the parameter list as an indication that it is an output parameter, not merely an internal variable.

If your instructor is being extremely picky, then perhaps you can get some slack by pointing out some apparent errors in the pseudocode:

- As already mentioned, `Nearest` is not a parameter, and it is written to but never read from.
- It looks like the conditional `if Dist[u] ← w(uv) < Dist[v] then` should instead be `if Dist[u] + w(uv) < Dist[v] then`.  (You have implemented the correct version, which could be construed as another difference from the pseudocode.)
- It looks like `Parent[r] ← u` should be `Parent[v] ← u`.

Of course, it could be that your instructor wanted you to implement the pseudocode exactly, errors and all ....

As a matter of strategy, I would have tried to use variable names better matching the pseudocode.  I don't think it would be fair for your instructor to reject the code on those grounds, but comparing the C++ code to the pseudocode would have been easier for *everyone* if you had stuck a bit closer with your names.

While I'm talking about your code, by the way, I observe that although your `minDistance()` function appears to implement the pseudocode's requirements, it does so in an inefficient way (and Dijkstra isn't particularly efficient to begin with).  The usual approach uses a min-heap to track nodes that have been seen but not yet visited, which reduces the cost of selecting the min-distance node from O(n) to O(log n).  Not that it matters for so few elements as you are testing on, of course, but for large graphs the difference is enormous.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake, And my lecturer agree with the mistake as below:-

- It looks like the conditional if Dist[u] ← w(uv) < Dist[v] then should instead be if Dist[u] + w(uv) < Dist[v] then. (You have implemented the correct version, which could be construed as another difference from the pseudocode.)

- It looks like Parent[r] ← u should be Parent[v] ← u.


 [Nearest] is equals to MIN ?

Answer (score -1):

On problem is i belive your minDistance function, it seems that you only update unvisited nodes ( line 10 if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[n] <= min)). I guess this is wrong. Consider the following graph (nodes V={n1, n2, n3, n4} with the following distances d(n1, n2) = 10; d(n1,n3) = 3; d(n3,n2) = 3 ( all others are infinity).

Starting in n1 you discover n2 with the cost of 10

you discover also n3 with the cost of 3

from n2 you dont discover the shorter path to n2 ( n1-n3-n2), because you marked n2 already as visited.

I'm not sure, if i'm wright. If not dont blame me.

Comment: No, it matches the pseudocode (and Dijkstra generally) that `minDistance()` considers only unvisited nodes.  In the pseudocode, that corresponds to the condition "over all u such that InTheTree[u] = .false.".  Dijkstra implementations ordinarily use a min-heap to manage this selection, which is more efficient, but the pseudocode doesn't require that.